# Does current location in CV factor into employers search results?

Tags: support, jobs, search, location

There are two places to input locations in your stackoverflow careers CV.  One is current location, and the other is where you'd like to work.

Imagine you put CityA in your current location, and CityB in where you want to work.  Would employers searching for candidates for a job in CityA see your CV?

Comment: While this is hosted on `stackoverflow.com` it's not relevant to meta.

Comment: @Josh this *is* relevant to Meta because Careers is a service Stack Overflow offers

Comment: The Careers site links you to meta.stackoverflow for questions

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, +1 then. Well, +1 when someone edits so I can change my vote. Well, looks like retagging it counts as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how employers are performing a search.  If you put CityA in your current location you will be shown to employers searching in CityA who select they are unwilling to relocate candidates.  For employers who are willing to relocate (which is the default) you will be shown as a result for a search on CityB.

Comment: So StackOverflow careers makes the assumption that you're willing to consider another job in your current city.  That's unfortunate.  Thanks for the answer.